# Conditional Piecewise function in a set of differential equations

Tags: python-3.x, ode, piecewise, gekko

I am trying to implement a model, and I have this conditional Piecewise function, as part of the model.

[image: This the equation,I'm trying to implement]

---

where T_zone(=293) and T_in(=348) are previously defined constants, x2 and x5 are variables dependent on other equations that depend on T_in and T_out.

All of them have defined initial values.

---

```py
temperature_zone=293.0
T_in = m.Var(value=temperature_zone) 
T_zone = m.Var(value=temperature_zone) 
x2 = m.Var(value=temperature_zone)
x5 = m.Var(value=temperature_zone)
Tout = m.Var(value=temperature_zone)
Tp1out=m.Var(value=temperature_zone)

m1out=m.if3(((2.0*(x2))-T_in-T_zone), 0, ((2.0*(x2))-T_in-T_zone))
m.Equation(T_p1out== T_zone+m1out)
m2out=m.if3(((2.0*(x5))-T_p1out-T_zone), 0, ((2.0*(x5))-T_p1out-T_zone))
m.Equation(T_out == T_zone+m2out)
```

In the code above, I tried separating the equation into 2 parts, and make the result of the if condition to be added as an additional variable to the base/minimum value, and it resulted in no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some things to consider:

- If `T_in` and `T_zone` are constants then use `m.Const` or `m.Param` instead of `m.Var`. Otherwise, they can be adjusted by the solver.
- A single `m.if3` function is sufficient for this problem. You can define two `m.if3` statements and then add the output but then you are creating additional binary variables that will make your problem more difficult to solve.
- The `condition` determines whether `T_out=T_zone (condition<0)` or whether `T_out=2*x5-2*x2+T_in (condition>=0)`.
- The value of `T_in` is 348.0, not `temperature_zone (293.0)`.

Here is a complete script for the problem you posed.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
temperature_zone=293.0
T_in = m.Const(value=348.0) 
T_zone = m.Const(value=temperature_zone) 
x2 = m.Var(value=temperature_zone)
x5 = m.Var(value=temperature_zone)
condition = 2*x5-2*x2+T_in-T_zone
Tout=m.if3(condition, T_zone, 2*x5-2*x2+T_in)
m.solve()
```

The [APOPT solver](https://apopt.com) finds the solution in two iterations. Note that `x2` and `x5` are additional degrees of freedom in this example and that equations are still needed to specify their values.

```
 Number of state variables:              6
 Number of total equations: -            3
 Number of slack variables: -            2
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              1

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    2 Obj:  0.00E+00 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   0.00E+00 Lowest Leaf:   0.00E+00 Gap:   0.00E+00
Iter:     2 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  0.00E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.390000000537839E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```